# Segmentation fault using AES/GCM with EVP interfaces

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I found some demo ([wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption), [github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/evp/aesgcm.c)) but they don't work. And running the code blow which I write refer to the code in above link got `Segmentation fault(core dumped)`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *ciphertext;
    char *key;
    char *iv;
    char *plaintext;

     key = "AES256-GCM-KEY-1234567890abcdefg";
     iv = "8a9cef0205a3";
     ciphertext = "uatBMo8k7EAnDQuNK4CHASJerQZpCWv86PGditzdYnQV9uqotQ==";
     plaintext = "";

    decrypt(ciphertext, NULL, 0, NULL, key, iv, plaintext);
    return 0;
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, unsigned char *aad, int aad_len, unsigned char *tag, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext){
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len, ret;
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN,strlen(iv),NULL);
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx,plaintext, &len, ciphertext, strlen(ciphertext));//"segmentation fault"
    ret = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext, &len);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    printf(ret > 0 ? "success!\n" : "failed!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused, how to use this api to  decrypt without Authenticate?

Comment: You never set the cipher to AES/GCM; you should have a call to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` with `EVP_aes_128_gcm` or `EVP_aes_256_gcm` somewhere. Also see [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @jww yes! it works now, i'm tooooooo careless. thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate memory to your pointer (all of them)

```
key = malloc(sizeof(*key) * strlen("AES256-GCM-KEY-1234567890abcdefg") + 1);
```

You should compile your main with theses flags (if gcc is the compiler): `-W -Wall -Wextra` it will tell you that your pointer are uninitialized

Comment: sorry i made some mistake about variable name，it's not pointer problem.@jww has solved my problem ,but thank you anyway.